# cypher-dsl java unwind a collection

Tags: java, cypher

I'm new to cypher-dsl java.
The problem is we need a dynamic relationship type in a query, but this isn't supported yet, nor does it work with spring spel, in the current query we have.
We decided therefore to use cypher-dsl.
I need to build a statement that uses unwind with a collection of strings and can't find a way to do it.

```
"MATCH (source:Browse{nodeId: $sourceId}) 
 UNWIND $destIds as destId 
 MERGE (destination:Phantom{nodeId: destId}) "
```

The $destIds in the 2nd line is where the collection is used now, in a spring-data @Query annotation.

I'd love an example or an explanation how to do that.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

To create the cypher query you can do something like:

```
public static void main (String... args){
    var browse = Cypher.node("Browse")
            .withProperties("nodeId", Cypher.parameter("sourceId"))
            .named("source");
    var destIds = List.of("dest1", "dest2");
    var listExpression = Cypher.listOf(destIds.stream().map(s -> (Expression)literalOf(s)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    var dest = Cypher.name("destId");
    var destination = Cypher.node("Phantom")
            .withProperties("node", dest)
            .named("destination");
    var statement = match(browse)
            .unwind(listExpression).as(dest)
            .merge(destination)
            .build();
    String s = statement.getCypher();
}
```